# Angular - How to make my error page to always be on top

Tags: html, css, angular

In my Angular-14 project, I am implementing ngx-bootstrap modal.
Also I have customized error page.

I observe that whenever there's error and the application redirects to the customised error page, the modal form is always on top, and the error page is behind.

How do I correct this and make the customized error page to always be on top?

Thanks

Comment: add your code so people can know how to help..

Comment: code and screenshot of the UI issue